# Apply function over list of functions

Tags: r

I am using the R library [docstring](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docstring/index.html) to generate documentation of functions.

I have a list of functions, and therefore I would like to map or lapply the docstring function over it. I can't figure out how that would work.

```
library(docstring)

test1 = function(x) {
  #' my docstring 
  #' 
  #' with some description
  x + 1
}

test2 = function(y) {
  #' another docstring
  #' 
  #' witn more descriptions
  y + 10
}

docstring(test1); docstring(test2) # works

f = lsf.str()
lapply(f, docstring)

Error in docstring_to_roxygen(fun, fun_name = fun_name, default_title = default_title) : 
  This function doesn't have any detectable docstring
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't understand why you create a list of character strings with the function names instead of a list of functions.
2. You need to specify the function name if you pass unnamed functions.
3. I would use a `for` loop because `docstring` returns `NULL`.

This works:

```
for (foo in f) docstring(fun = getFunction(foo), fun_name = foo)
```